# If a function is injective in category of finite sets, then retraction exists?

Tags: category-theory

**Definitions**

A map$f: A \rightarrow B$ is **injective** if statement P: ($x_1, x_2: T \rightarrow A$) $f \circ x_1=f \circ x_2$ implies $x_1=x_2$ holds for every $T$ and and every $x_1, x_2$.

A map $r: B \rightarrow A$ is a **retraction** for a map $f: A \rightarrow B$ iff $r \circ f=1_A$.

I am doing problem in second column of following snapshot's table, i.e. finding number of retractions that can exist for a given map $j:A \rightarrow X$.

[image: A snapshot from Lawvere and Schanuel's Conceptual Mathematics]

I thought that authors falsely assume that if $j$ is **injective**, then atleast 1 retraction exist in their statement: "unless $j$ is injective, there will be no retraction for $j$", because injective map does not imply existence of retraction if $|A| = 0$ and $|X| > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, my doubt has cleared up and I realized that authors meant that, if $j$ is not injective, then there does not exist any retraction in category of finite sets.

In fact, existence of retraction $r:B \rightarrow A$ to a morphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ implies that $f$ is injective in any category. The proof as follows:

Suppose $x_1, x_2: T \rightarrow A$.

Now, to prove that $f$ is injective, one only needs to show that if $f \circ x_1 = f \circ x_2$ then $x_1=x_2$.

Using identity axiom:

$$x_1=1_A \circ x_1$$

Now, it is known that $r \circ f=1_A$, therefore

$$x_1=(r \circ f) \circ x_1$$

Now, using associativity axiom,

$$x_1 = r \circ (f \circ x_1)$$

Now, use $f \circ x_1 = f\circ x_2$,

$$x_1=r \circ (f \circ x_2)$$

Now, again use associative identity,

$$x_1=(r \circ f) \circ x_2$$

Since, $r \circ f=1_A$

$$x_1=1_A \circ x_2$$

Using identity axiom,

$$x_1 = x_2$$

Therefore, $f$ is **injective**.